# About the usage of "so small"

Tags: nouns, uncountable-nouns

Recently, I have been reading a book about TOEFL grammar.
I came across this multiple-choice problem:

I have _______ money left.

(A) a great number
(B) so small
(C) only a little
(D) only a few

The answer given is (C). I don't understand why (B) is not the correct answer. Does anyone know the reason? Thank you very much.

Comment: 'So small' isn't used directly before a noun. 'So small a fault should be overlooked.' // 'I have such a small amount of money left.' // Interestingly, 'little' _is a quantifier_ (it also exists, of course, as an adjective) _that can be used here_: 'I have little money left' and with premodification 'I have so little money left'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you very much. :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between "little" and "small"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31216/difference-between-little-and-small) // On a different note, I've edited your question to sound more natural.

Comment: To add to Edwin's comment: "Money" is an uncountable noun - uncountable nouns are graded by a quantifier that indicates amount of something. Small is not a quantifier.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I will read 'Difference between "little" and "small"'. Thank you.

Comment: @Greybeard Thank you very much! :-)